# Same function but different frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a mini timer programme, but I have a question: each frame uses the same function called setTimer, so what frame should I reference in the setTimer function? Here is my code:

```
def createFrames(self): 
        self.timer1_frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="red")
        self.timer1_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer1_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.timer2_frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="blue")
        self.timer2_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer2_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.timer3_frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="orange")
        self.timer3_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer3_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        
        self.timer4_frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="yellow")
        self.timer4_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer4_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def createWidgets(self):   
        self.setTimer1_button = Button(self.timer1_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=self.setTimer)
        self.setTimer1_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)
        
        self.setTimer2_button = Button(self.timer2_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=self.setTimer)
        self.setTimer2_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30, pady=20)

        self.setTimer3_button = Button(self.timer3_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=self.setTimer)
        self.setTimer3_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

        self.setTimer4_button = Button(self.timer4_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=self.setTimer)
        self.setTimer4_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=20)

    def setTimer(self):
        
        self.hoursLabel = Label(root, text="Hours: ")
        self.minutesLabel = Label(root, text="Minutes: ")
        self.secondsLabel = Label(root, text="Seconds: ")
```

As you can see, I'm referencing root in my setTimer function but I don't think it's correct, what would I put there instead so it knows which frame I'm referring to, rather than having to write 4 lots of the same code (is this possible?)

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: define `def setTimer(self, frame):` with  `Label(frame, ...)` and then use `command=lambda:self.setTimer(self.timer1_frame)`

Comment: or create own widget with one `Frame` and one `Button` which access this frame - and then use this widget 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create method with argument `frame` which is used in `Label`

```
def setTimer(self, frame):
    self.hoursLabel = Label(frame, text="Hours: ")
    # ... rest ...
```

and then you can use `lambda` in `command=` to assign function with argument

```
self.setTimer1_button = tk.Button..., command=lambda:self.setTimer(self.timer1_frame))
```

And it works.

But it has one problem: in all frames it assigns labels to the same variables `self.hoursLabel`, etc. so you can't access labels to change text (ie. to update time). You would have to use separated variables but it would need to keep them on list or dictionary and use `frame` as key.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window():

    def __init__(self):
        # dictionary for labels
        self.labels = {}
        
        self.createFrames()
        self.createWidgets()
        
    def createFrames(self): 
        self.timer1_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="red")
        self.timer1_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer1_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.timer2_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="blue")
        self.timer2_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer2_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.timer3_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="orange")
        self.timer3_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer3_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        
        self.timer4_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=300, background="yellow")
        self.timer4_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer4_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def createWidgets(self):   
        self.setTimer1_button = tk.Button(self.timer1_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=lambda:self.setTimer(self.timer1_frame))
        self.setTimer1_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)
        
        self.setTimer2_button = tk.Button(self.timer2_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=lambda:self.setTimer(self.timer2_frame))
        self.setTimer2_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

        self.setTimer3_button = tk.Button(self.timer3_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=lambda:self.setTimer(self.timer3_frame))
        self.setTimer3_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

        self.setTimer4_button = tk.Button(self.timer4_frame, text="SET TIMER", command=lambda:self.setTimer(self.timer4_frame))
        self.setTimer4_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

    def setTimer(self, frame):
        self.hoursLabel   = tk.Label(frame, text="Hours: ")
        self.minutesLabel = tk.Label(frame, text="Minutes: ")
        self.secondsLabel = tk.Label(frame, text="Seconds: ")

        self.hoursLabel.grid(row=1)
        self.minutesLabel.grid(row=2)
        self.secondsLabel.grid(row=3)

        # remember labels in dictionary
        self.labels[frame] = [self.hoursLabel, self.minutesLabel, self.secondsLabel]
        
        # start update time
        self.updateTimer(frame, 0)
                    
    def updateTimer(self, frame, seconds):
        
        secondsLabel = self.labels[frame][2]
        secondsLabel['text'] = "Seconds: {}".format(seconds)
        seconds += 1
        root.after(1000, self.updateTimer, frame, seconds)
        
root = tk.Tk()
Window()
root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

It can be simpler to use `Frame` to create own widget with one `Frame`, one `Button`, all `Labels` and variables needed in timer. And later use this widget 4 times in main window.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyTimer(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.hours = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.seconds = 0
        
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="SET TIMER", command=self.set_timer)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

        self.hours_label   = None
        self.minutes_label = None
        self.seconds_label = None

    def set_timer(self):
        if self.hours_label is None:
            self.hours_label   = tk.Label(self, text="Hours: ")
            self.minutes_label = tk.Label(self, text="Minutes: ")
            self.seconds_label = tk.Label(self, text="Seconds: ")

            self.hours_label.grid(row=1)
            self.minutes_label.grid(row=2)
            self.seconds_label.grid(row=3)

        # reset time
        self.hours = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.seconds = 0
        
        # start updating time
        self.update_timer()
        
    def update_timer(self):
        self.hours_label['text']   = "Hours: {}".format(self.hours)
        self.minutes_label['text'] = "Minutes: {}".format(self.minutes)
        self.seconds_label['text'] = "Seconds: {}".format(self.seconds)
        self.seconds += 1

        if self.seconds == 60:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes += 1

        if self.minutes == 60:
            self.minutes = 0
            self.hours += 1
            
        # update again after 1000ms (1s)
        root.after(1000, self.update_timer)
        
class Window():

    def __init__(self):
        self.createFrames()
        
    def createFrames(self): 
        self.timer1_frame = MyTimer(root, width=300, height=300, background="red")
        self.timer1_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer1_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.timer2_frame = MyTimer(root, width=300, height=300, background="blue")
        self.timer2_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer2_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.timer3_frame = MyTimer(root, width=300, height=300, background="orange")
        self.timer3_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer3_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        
        self.timer4_frame = MyTimer(root, width=300, height=300, background="yellow")
        self.timer4_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.timer4_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
root = tk.Tk()
Window()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea you could create your own widgets with Tkinter, this makes a lot of sense!